# Saving changes to LLVM BasicBlock Pass

Tags: llvm

I successfully added some Metadata to a Basic Block in LLVM. Then I used  `Mod->dump()` to display it on the screen.

The data is added successfully to my byte code, i.e. metadata is displayed on the screen.

My problem is that these changes are not updated in my original file.

How can I solve this problem?

```
class BasicBlock1 : public BasicBlockPass {
public:
    BasicBlock1()
    : BasicBlockPass(ID)
  {}

    virtual bool runOnBasicBlock(BasicBlock &BB) {

        Value *A[] = {MDString::get(getGlobalContext(), "mymetadata")};
        MDNode *Node = MDNode::get(getGlobalContext(), A);

        for (BasicBlock::iterator ii = BB.begin(), ii_e = BB.end();
              ii != ii_e; ++ii) {
                ii->setMetadata("XXX", Node);
              }

        return true;
    }
    static char ID;
};

char FunctionPrint::ID = 0;
char BasicBlock1::ID =0;


int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  Module *Mod = ParseIRFile(argv[1], Err, getGlobalContext());

  PM.add(new BasicBlock1());
  PM.run(*Mod);
  Mod->dump();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If it's displayed with `dump()` it should be in the file as well, as writing to a file uses the same code as `dump()`. Can you update the question to show how, exactly, do you save the modified module to a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write:

> The data is added successfully to my byte code, i.e. metadata is displayed on the screen.
>
> My problem is that these changes are not updated in my original file.

In your code snippet, you do not write your modified module anywhere, you just print it to the output. You can write it using:

```
std::string ErrorInfo;
raw_fd_ostream OS(argv[1], ErrorInfo, sys::fs::F_Binary);
if (ErrorInfo.empty()) WriteBitcodeToFile(*Mod, OS);
```